# How to record H.264 video source directly to file in Windows.Media.Capture

Tags: video, video-streaming, h.264, video-capture, ms-media-foundation

I want to develop a Computer Vision algorithm that takes webcam video as input. For this I need to record a training dataset of videos in the same format as the images I’ll be getting in production.

I’m concerned that encoding video files in a lossy format, then decoding them for training will degrade and otherwise change the training images so they won’t be exactly the same as the images I’ll see in production.

Now, I see that my webcam (running on Surface Pro 3) has H264 video sources and YUY2 video sources.

So I figure – the H264 is the source of the images and the YUY2 are probably decoded images. If I record the H264 directly to a file, and later decode that file, then the decoded images will be equivalent to what I’d get from the YUY2 video source. I did not encode new video thereby changing it, but rather used the source H264 – which was already encoded.

My questions are:

1. Is this assumption true? Is the H264 feed the source and YUY2 the product of that source? How can I check?
2. How do I record from the H264 video source directly to files without decoding and re-encoding?

I’m using the new Windows.Media.Capture API – but I’ll use other APIs if necessary.

Comment: Forgot to note I'm on x64 .NET. Windows.Media.Capture is not only for UWP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surface Pro 3 (unlike Surface Pro 4 by the way) is equipped with a camera capable of [H.264 hardware compression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj218765), which is the reason you are seeing both YUY2 and H264 as available options.

It is the camera which compresses video, so YUY2 is the raw feed and H264 is its derivative.

> Is this assumption true? Is the H264 feed the source and YUY2 the product of that source? How can I check?

No, it is the opposite.

> How do I record from the H264 video source directly to files without decoding and re-encoding?

Read H264 and route it to the multiplexer to produce MP4 files with H264 video track. It is definitely possible with Windows Media Foundation's Source Reader and Sink Writer, possibly also with Media Session API, and I am not sure about Windows.Media.Capture which is presumably a layer on top of the mentioned.

Comment: All right. If H.264 is the derivative then I see no advantage to using the camera encoded feed over re-encoding in software, as I lose the original data either way.

Comment: The advantage could be zero CPU load for compression (although, you still have an option to capture raw and compress using hardware H.264 compressor in many cases), and then the camera might be capable of compressing with specific parameters/modes such as SVC. Finally, doing capture in H.264 you in many cases can achieve higher resolution/rate combinations.

Comment: All of that is true. It's not clear to me how to record that stream with MediaCapture without re-encoding. I'm troubled by it's ability to "sneakily" re-encode without any indication that that is happening. I hope to use Windows Media Foundation following your advice and record the stream directly.

Comment: This is how Media Foundation works. In this API, Microsoft decided to do a lot on their side without giving details. Then Media Foundation is layered and the lower level you choose to interact it with, the more understanding you have. At Windows.Media.Capture we are supposed to be happy that the thing at all works, without asking too much questions.

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand you correctly, you're saying that the webcam you have exposes two different possible streams: an H.264 encoded stream and a YUY2 encoded stream. Your assumption is that the webcam exposes the h.264 feed as it's primary format and then decompresses it into the YUY2 format.

This is most certainly not the case, the YUY2 format is the raw data that is captured by the webcam and the h.264 feed is the compressed format of that data. So you can rest assured that it is not lossy.

There are some examples out there that describe how to write the data to file.

Answer (score 0):

You can check CameraFrames sample from the UWP SDK: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraFrames

Basically, it creates a MediaFrameReader for the webcam and subscribes to it's FrameArrived event. You should have access to the H264 frame there and feed it to a Sink Writer for instance. Or use MediaCapture.StartRecordToCustomSinkAsync, where you need to supply your custom IMediaExtension media sink. Check SimpleCommunication sample: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SimpleCommunication

Comment: I’m recording to a storage file with MediaCapture.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync. Why do I need the CustomSink?
The problem is that the file gets a 640 width resolution **regardless of the input resolution** indicating it's been re-encoded.<br>
According to the [MediaCapture API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.mediacapture): *If the native type is H.264, you can record using a video media type with type identical to the native type. You cannot add an effect to an H.264 native type stream*